# Screencrawler site (maybe?) copying content from SP.SE

Tags: support

I was searching for some answer on an issue I'm facing and I fell over this site:

http://sharepoint.searchalleasy.com/

It has the exact same layout as SP.SE and the exact same content.

Comment: Looks like something to ask employees of SE, possibly on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). Good catch!

Comment: @BennySkogberg I'll post it there as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know! Sorry for not replying sooner; I saw this on Meta SE and didn't remember to post back here afterwards.